# css is not recognizig -webkit-transform

Tags: css, webkit

I am trying to make the exact copy of this project done in CSS, HTML and JS, [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/WhiteWolfWizard/pen/izhHd)

When i run the code it runs alright but the JS file is giving me error in these two

```
#progress aside span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);      
}

#progress aside span:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(1.1);
}
```

I am new to web-programming so I will really appreciate if anyone could help me in it.

Regards.

Comment: Specially, what error are you getting?

Comment: Where do you get what error?

Comment: Is that really the beginning of your css file? If yes, a starting rule is missing.

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-transform` is only recognizable in browsers using the **webkit engine** (*e.g: Google Chrome, Opera, Safari etc*). This `-webkit-` is known as vendor prefixes used by browsers using webkit engine.

> Browser prefixes are used to add new features that may not be part of a formal specification and to implement features in a specification that hasn’t been finalized.

You should include all other vendor prefixes as well.

```
#progress aside span:hover {
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(-5deg) scale(1.1); /*For webkit browsers*/
    -moz-transform:  rotate(-5deg) scale(1.1); /* For Mozilla based browsers */
    -ms-transform:  rotate(-5deg) scale(1.1); /* For Microsoft browsers */
    -o-transform:  rotate(-5deg) scale(1.1); /* For older versions of opera */
    transform:  rotate(-5deg) scale(1.1); /* Default */
}
```

Comment: I answered with the same thing, the OP says its not the issue :/

Comment: @Brian Sorry, it took a long time for me to answer the question. Didn't noticed yours before. Had a disconnection from internet actually.